# SSIS creates too much connections to DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sybase

For data loading I use an SSIS package (VS2010) on MSSQL 2012. It loads data from Sybase ASE (ODBC) to MSSQL 2012 (OLEDB). Everything works fine and it uses a small amount of connection to Sybase.

Then I migrated my package to SSIS (VS2013) on MSSQL 2014 and now I have a strange situation.

When I open my package in VS2013 it create one connection to Sybase for each dataflow step from devenv.exe. Next I run my package and it creates one more connection for each dataflow step from DtsDebugHost.exe and during run it creates even more connections from DtsDebugHost.exe and almost all connections are in a state of "AWAITING COMMAND". I have license limit of 250 connections to Sybase and my package breaks this limit.

Why is this strange behavior happening in 2014 SSIS? How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Why the difference between versions, I have no answer.

If I were to hazard a guess, SSIS is trying to quickly validate the entirety of your package and is opening multiple connections and assigning validation work per connection. So, parallel validation versus serial validation.

The resolution though is to set the `RetainSameConnection` property on the ASE connection manager to True. This will keep SSIS from opening multiple connections an instead force everything to use one connection.

Comment: It`s not exactly my situation. I knew about RetainSameConnection and don`t use it at all.
I have 26 dataflow tasks in my package. SSIS on MSSQL2012 and VS 2010 create 26 sybase connections using one ODBC connection manager, it`s ok. But SSIS on MSSQL2014 and VS2013 create each time random amount of connections, but always twice bigger than 26.